# Laravel's Foreach syntax error

Tags: php, laravel

Hello can anyone tell me what im doing wrong with this laravel's foreach loop :/ Keep getting the below error or an undefined variable of posts if i change the foreach loop without using session:

```
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 


   @foreach(session('posts') as $post)

   @endforeach
```

Controller:

```
 public function getDashboard(){

        $posts = Post::all();

        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(compact('posts'));

    }
```

Or if I do this other version i get undefined $posts in the view dashboard:

Controller:

```
 public function getDashboard(){

        $posts = Post::all();

        return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);

    }
```

dashboard view:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

@endforeach
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [

    'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard',
    'middleware' => 'auth'

]);
```

Comment: It seems session doesn't work for some reason. Please put `{{ dd(session('post')) }}` before the `foreach(session('posts') ...` and show the dump.

Comment: Doing this now as we speak. One sec.

Comment: When i refresh the dashboard page i get view with no styling just content.

Comment: And a null value displays.

Comment: I have updated my code to include routes.

Comment: I feel so stupid lol

Comment: ok, do not use session here. Just use `return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);` and `@foreach($posts as $post)`. After that run `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan route:clear` commands. Then load `yourdomain.com/dashboard` page you usually trying ot load.

Comment: I fixed it something silly.

Comment: so this solved the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redirecting to the dashboard route. Any arguments provided using `with()` won't automatically be included in the view.

Instead, get the posts in the code that returns the view. Example:

```
$posts = Post::all();
return view('dashboard', compact('posts'));
```

The method that you're currently using flashes to the session, which realistically, isn't needed at all.

---

I see that you've updated your question. To answer properly, we'd need the code of the dashboard view.

Comment: @steven is the foreach loop in the dashboard view?

Comment: It is in the dashboard view.

Comment: @steven have you tried dumping out the content of `$posts`? `{{ dd($posts) }}`

Comment: Doing this now as we speak. One sec.

Comment: When i refresh the dashboard page i get view with no styling just content.

Comment: And a null value displays.

Comment: Try doing `dd($posts)` before you return the view in your controlled method.

Comment: Did that still - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in `controller` and it should work just fine.

Controller:

```
public function getDashboard(){

    $posts = Post::all()->get();

    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('posts', $posts);

}
```

Dashboard view:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

@endforeach
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [

'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
'as' => 'dashboard',
'middleware' => 'auth'

]);
```